# Multiple layers of Application Data folders - Windows7

Tags: windows-7, command

In a command window If I navigate to c:\users\me and do "dir", I see 13 folders but no files.  If I do "dir /s", I see thousands of files, but what bothers me is that I see paths like this:

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data...  then, finally, something like Microsoft\VisualStudio or Google\Chrome or so on.

What is it with the layers and layers of Application Data folders?  If I search using AgentRansack for some file deep down into these layers, I may see 15 or 20 instances of a file at different levels in this hierarchy.  If I delete one, it says, "Delete Failed", but it removes it from the list. So, it looks like there is something "virtual" about these folders...  Any clues?

Comment: Here is some additional info. Basically it's for backwards compatibility. MS added Everyone:Deny permissions to the junction. https://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH156919

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DaddyMan posted this (paraphrased):

The Application Data 'folder' keeps replicating itself as a sub-folder when you alter permissions for the Application Data folder, usually by giving yourself full permissions for the c:\users\ folder.  The Application Data folder is actually a junction, which points back to its parent folder.

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Application Data\

points to

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\

This is done to prevent recursion when a non-Windows 7 aware application scans the Application Data 'folder', and it's also the reason for the "Access is denied" message you get on certain folders in c:\users\.

[The original link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/why-are-there-multiple-layers-of-application-data/4ec2c92c-a691-432b-b86a-c76d2b9a3faa?tab=MoreHelp#tabs).

Also, Shawn B. Keene - MVP - posted this:

Anytime an application tries to save a file to a naughty location (such as C:\Windows or C:\Program Files), Windows will force the actual save to end up at a place inside your user folder instead (C:\Users\Username\LocalSettings\VirtualStore\Program Files).  It tricks the program into thinking that the file really did go to the Program Files folder, but in reality it's somewhere inside your user folder.

This virtualization (tricking the program) is required so that badly-created apps that save to naughty locations will still work.  The alternative is that the program tries to save and then crashes when it can't access the Program Files folder.  If Windows didn't do this, the program would require administrator access every time it runs -- which is very insecure, plus would make the program impossible to use in corporate environments where users aren't allowed to be administrators.

Rest assured that the multple layers you are seeing are a result of folder redirection and virtualization (also known as junction points).  There's no need to clean these up or correct it, and you are well advised to avoid exploring those files.

For better results, save your TCW files to your Documents folder instead of Program Files or elsewhere, which will prevent any virtualization weirdness.

The original link is [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/multiple-occurances-of-same-file/ac11fe50-e945-e011-9577-d485645a8348).

Comment: answers with only links are susceptible to link rot. Can you paraphrase the answers so the OP has some idea what to do, leaving the links for people who want more details? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-do-i-properly-write-an-answer-that-references-my-blog/94027#94027

Comment: I'm also seeing this on a recently-installed Windows 10 system, when I look at it through Microsoft's OpenSSH port's sftp server (mounted as an sshfs).  The nesting only goes about 8 levels deep, and then stops.  It doesn't appear to be causing any problems, but it feels a little odd.  If I sftp to a Linux host though, it also treats symlinks to directories as directories.