# Invalid path generated in remote command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a command on a remote machine. I thought that I gave it a simple DIR command. However, the path generated keeps recursing the `Application Data` directory. PSVersion 5.0.10586.117

```
PS X:\Scripts\PSAutomation> Get-Content .\stest2.ps1
#Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

$Computername = "NOMURA"

$Sess = New-PSSession $Computername

$job = Invoke-Command `
    -ScriptBlock {
        & cmd.exe /C DIR /S /B C:\Users\pwatson
        & cmd.exe /C EXIT /B 7
    } `
    -Session $Sess -AsJob

While ($job.State -ne "Completed")
{
    Write-Verbose "waiting for it"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1             # <Int32>
}

$remoteoutput = Receive-Job -Id $job.Id -Keep
$remoteoutput
```

Here is the execution output.

```
PS X:\Scripts\PSAutomation> .\stest2.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
VERBOSE: waiting for it
The directory name C:\Users\pwatson\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application
Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application
Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data is too long.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The directory n...ta is too long.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : NOMUrA

The directory name C:\Users\pwatson\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application
Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application
Data\Application Data\Application Data\Apps\2.0\Data\JKANDEOW.ZBN is too long.
The directory name C:\Users\pwatson\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application
Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application
Data\Application Data\Application Data\Apps\2.0\WA88X1RN.R7H\WQGJ5CWJ.XPH is too long.
```

This is not the same as [Multiple layers of Application Data folders - Windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913784/multiple-layers-of-application-data-folders-windows7)

The `DIR` command is being run on a remote machine. When I have an RDP session on the remote machine, this problem does not appear. It is only when I run `DIR` as a PowerShell remote job that the problem occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple layers of Application Data folders - Windows7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913784/multiple-layers-of-application-data-folders-windows7) - it's a backwards compatibility thing, and default folder permissions mean you can't get stuck in that loop. Your folder permissions are likely changed from the default.

Comment: try `cmd.exe /C DIR /A:-L /S /B C:\Users\pwatson`, note the `/A:-L` to exclude reparse points.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - /A:-L is a great idea. Sounds like just what is needed. It does not change the output. Same result.

Comment: Weird, in my test it fixed the problem, I tested with a remote Server 2016 but only in an interactive remote session. No `Invoke-Command -AsJob`