# Multiple Wildcards in C#

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

While recursively traversing through c:\Users, I've ran into an issue where c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data ... goes on forever.

I found an article [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dc01054b-610b-415b-a48e-d296fa2b77ae/repeated-shortcuts-to-application-data-in-userappdatalocalapplication-data?forum=w7itprogeneral) that talks about what the shortcut \Application Data\ is and why it's there.

Also related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913784/multiple-layers-of-application-data-folders-windows7).

What I need to do is continue looping past this subfolder.

Is there a way to do something like this? :

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path)
{
    do stuff
}
foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(path)
{
    if (subdir == "c:\\Users\\*\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data\\*")
    {
        continue;
    }
    recusivecall(subdir);
}
```

Comment: It won't do that for you. You could write a method that takes a username and searches `$@"c:\Users\{userName}\AppData\Local\Application Data\"`. Enumerate the username directories under c:\Users and pass each one in turn to that method. Or you could get ambitious and write a multi-level wildcard directory enumerator. It'd be a fun exercise; path parsing is easy in Windows.

Comment: `if (subDir.ToLower().StartsWith("c:\\users\\") && subDir.Contains("\\appdata\\local\\application data\\")) continue;` If you have more wildcards, you may have to use the `string.IndexOf()` method to ensure that the sections you're searching for are in the proper order, or just use a regular expression.

Comment: Another idea (if you wanted to process the files one time) would be to keep track of where you've been by storing each path in a list, and then `if (pathList.Contains(subdir)) continue; pathList.Add(subdir); recursiveCall(subdir);`

Comment: @RufusL Would the list eventually hold every file and subfile or just the files in the current directory?

Comment: every directory, to prevent hitting a junction that brings you back to a place you've been before.

Comment: okay. That makes sense. If it doesn't slow down the program, that may be an easier way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding so quickly!

Doing the following worked:

```
if (subDirectory.ToLower().StartsWith("c:\\users\\") && subDirectory.ToLower().Contains("\\appdata\\local\\application data"))
{
    continue;
}
```

Credit: Rufus L